# UIATarget.onAlert doesn't work in Instruments 5.0?

Tags: ios, alert, instruments, xcode5, ios-ui-automation

This code used to work well in Automation test with Instruments 4.6:

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
    var title = alert.name();
    UIALogger.logWarning("Alert with title ’" + title + "’ encountered!");

    return false; // use default handler
}
```

I've upgraded to XCode 5.0 and this code doesn't work anymore. There is no reaction to alerts -- onAlert is never called.

Am I missing something or this is really broken by Apple?

Comment: Are you running it under iOS 7? Perhaps it's related to the OS version rather than the XCode's.

Comment: This use to work. Apple broke it in iOS 7. Alas, we have to file a bug report.

Comment: This probably may be related to iOS 7. Instruments automatically starts iOS 7 sumulator.
By the way, is there any way to tell Instruments which simulator to run?

Comment: Change the hardware, this will be started next time until you change again.

Comment: Nope, it always changes hardware to 'iPhone'. I'm running a universal app. With XCode 4.6 I used `defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator 'SimulateDevice' iPad` to set up the Simulator, but it doesn't work for XCode 5.

Answer (score 1):

Add a delay in. I had this same issue, and adding `UIATarget.localTarget().delay(5);` above fixed it. It seems, even though Apple does not recommend using the delay() function, I need it more and more, as elements can take a few seconds to show up. The alert was taking a while to appear and the script just went right over the onAlert.

Answer (score 1):

I put a `UIATarget.delay(0.2)` call immediately after the button tap invoke. It worked for me!